# Excel VBA loop/find Certain value

Tags: excel

I cannot get too specific due to my company regulations, so I will attempt to provide as much info as I can.
I have a for loop that goes through a list of names. In the loop, I have another loop that determines if a certain value should be assigned to to another list using the Name. Here is an Example
John Doe is number one on my list.
Jane Doe is number two.

```
John Doe 
17:20 = 1
17:25 = 2 
17:40 = 1 
17:45 = 0 
19:00 = 1
19:10 = 0
19:30 = 1
19:50 = 0
```

The Values are assigned based off of something that occurs during those times.
If X happens, Add 1 to the value.
If Z happens, subtract 1 from the value.

This will repeat for Jane Doe once the last row for John Doe is hit

(Everything above this I have already programed)
Where I am stuck, is I need to be able to have excel Subtract the time with the value of 0, from the time with the value of 1

```
For Example
17:00 = 1
17:10 = 2
17:20 = 3
17:30 = 4
17:35 = 3
17:40 = 2
17:50 = 1
18:00 = 0
```

I need excel to be able to subtract 17:00 from 18:00 based off of the value on the right.
I.e

```
If Range(B & [Whatever row]).Value = to 0 And Range(A & [Whatever row]).Value = 1 then 
subtract Range(A & [Whatever row]) from Range(A & [Whatever row])
```

But the problem is when I doe this, it will subtract 17:50 from 18:00 due to it falling in the same circumstance.
I fixed this through having ten different If else if circumstances, but I do not want to keep it that messy.

Does anyone have any other options?

I am fairly new to coding, so I am not too sure if there is anything else I can do other than that